# Simplification of discrete recursive expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I'm very new to Mathematica and I'm looking to simplify an expression where there are relations between discrete functions.

Suppose(this simplified expression):

```
Q(i+1) => c(i+1) - u(i+1)*( Q(i+1)-Q(i) )
```

and

```
Q(i) =< c(i) - u(i-1)*( Q(i)-Q(i-1) )
```

Where c(i) and u(i) are functions of i but are not specified.

Is there any way to get Mathematica to obtain an expression for Q(i+1)-Q(i)?

Comment: You can write it ```FullSimplify[Reduce[
  {Q[i + 1] >= c[i + 1] - u[i + 1] a[i],
   Q[i] <= c[i] - u[i - 1] a[i - 1]}, Reals]]``` where `a[i]` is taken to be `Q[i+1]-Q[i]`

Comment: Do you mean `<=` and `>=` instead of `=>` and `=<`?

Comment: To avoid confusion, are the given expressions inequalities?